# confirmar cierre de pestaña funciona en chrome pero no en firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox

Tengo el siguiente código

```
$(window).on('unload beforeunload', function() {
        return 'Are you sure want to LOGOUT the session ?';
    });
```

En chrome pide confirmación al hacer click en un vinculo, al cerrar la pestaña y al actualizar la pagina (F5).

El problema es que en Firefox solamente pide confirmación al hacer click en un vinculo, pero al cerrar la cierra directamente y al apretar F5 se actualiza sin ningún tipo de mensaje.

Answer (score 1):

En el siguiente link puedes encontrar explicacion a tu problema:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Hay una nota que dice:

> Note: To combat unwanted pop-ups, some browsers don't display prompts
>   created in beforeunload event handlers unless the page has been
>   interacted with. Moreover, some don't display them at all.

Que traducido mas o menos dice asi:

> Nota:  Para combatir pop-ups no deseados, algunos navegadores no
>   despliegan prompts creados en handlers con el evento onbeforeunload a
>   menos que la pagina haya tenido interaccion.  Ademas, algunos
>   navegadores no los despliegan para nada.

Comment: No me había dado cuenta. Esta bien entonces porque lo que busco es que avise si hay cambios en el formulario. Gracias